# Чтение текста с сайта c#

Tags: c#, парсер, текст

Недавно столкнулся с тем, что надо из текста на сайте выделить некоторую последовательность символов, однако в интернете описаны способы по извлечению HTML кода из страницы, но я знаю, что нужные мне данные будут в видимой части сайта, поэтому мне нужен только текст, без JavaScript, CSS, HTML тэгов - для меня это лишь лишний поток.
Отсюда, господа, возникает вопрос: как можно спарсить (прочитать) только текст с сайта и выделить некоторые символ?
Если ответа не будет, буду читать весь HTML текст.

Comment: Как то глупо парсить чисто текст, можете получить уйму пробелов, непонятных символов и др лабуды не интересной. Обычно текст (будь то статья, цитата или другой материал) расположены в одном теге (скажем `<div class="content">Текст</div>`), в таком случае достаточно просто получить данные в этом теге... Так может вам стоит работать с HTML? Либо я что то не понимаю, тогда было бы очень хорошо увидеть то, с чем требуется работать (код страницы)...

Comment: Страница (хоть видимая её часть, хоть невидимая) состоит из HTML разметки, а уже в этой разметке может быть нужный вам текст. Потому, чтобы этот текст достать, надо сначала распарсить HTML. Если, конечно, вы заранее знаете какой там текст должен быть, то можно всю разметку как текст разбирать, но я бы такое не советовал.

Comment: Мне нужен текст поста в ВКонтакте (P.S. и не только, если найду парсинг по тегу с классом, будет прекрасно, например поиск в коде по `<div class="current">КЛАСС</div>`). Сразу скажу, что всё было бы очень просто, если бы я мог использовать сторонние библиотеки (например, vk api), однако моя задача - сделать меньше кода как в объёме, так и в весе. 
Разметка поста в любой группе/странице выглядит так:
 `<div class="wall_post_text">Текст, текст, текст, <a href="/away.php?to=ССЫЛКА&amp;post=-число&amp;cc_key=" target="_blank">ССЫЛКА</a> 
<br> Новая строка текста
 </div>`

Comment: А с VK коллега, надо работать исключительно через API, благо он у него очень хороший. Весь текст спокойно можно получить скажем через [get](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get) или отдельное сообщение через [getById](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getById). У вас в разы меньше кода будет, чем парс HTML! Достаточно отправить правильно запрос (не обязательно сторонние библиотеки!).